# Reading serial numbers via OCR from a SensoPart VISOR Code Reader

Tags: ocr

I got a [SensoPart VISOR Code Reader](http://www.sensopart.com/en/products/vision-sensors-systems/code-reader) that takes images from a digitalprint machine. It comes with some default software, but I need to read the OCR images directly from the device (through their IP addresses) and interpret the OCR image to pick the serial numbers and store them in a database.

Comment: Please give us something to work with. What have you tried so far, and how was the result different from what you expected?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think your question might be a bit obscure for people to answer here. Did the code reader come with any documentation? Is there any documentation online? That might be your best bet. You might also want to check if there's an API for the default software they provide. If that all fails I would try contacting their support: http://www.sensopart.com/en/contact/sensopart-united-kingdom/inquiry?view=form Good luck! -Steve